# SUM and GROUP BY doubling the values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Query that should add the value of two tables and then check the difference between the results, however the result doubles the value of a column and multiplies the value of the other many times, I need help to solve this problem.

Oracle Data Base

Tables:
`funcionarios`
`funcionario_movimentos`
`funcionario_alimentacao`

Query

```sql
SELECT fn.uniorg_cgc, fn.id,  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 53, fa.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 153, fa.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 75, fa.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 175, fa.valor, 0)) AS Beneficio,  
SUM(DECODE(fm.cod_verba, 'E002', fm.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fm.cod_verba, 'E017', fm.valor, 0)) AS Folha,  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 53, fa.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 153, fa.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 75, fa.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fa.id_processo, 175, fa.valor, 0)) -  
SUM(DECODE(fm.cod_verba, 'E002', fm.valor, 0))+  
SUM(DECODE(fm.cod_verba, 'E017', fm.valor, 0)) AS Diferenca  
FROM  
funcionarios fn, funcionario_alimentacao fa, funcionario_movimentos fm  
WHERE fn.id = fa.id_funcionario  
AND fn.id = fm.id_funcionario  
AND fn.id = 4358  
AND fa.mes_comp = 8  
AND fa.ano_comp = 2022  
AND fm.mes_competencia = fa.mes_comp  
AND fm.ano_competencia = fa.ano_comp  
GROUP BY fn.uniorg_cgc, fn.id;
```

The result is as below:

| UNIORG_CGC | ID | BENEFICIO | FOLHA | DIFERENCA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMB CSC | 4358 | 53274 | 2049 | 52672 |

But expected was:

| UNIORG_CGC | ID | BENEFICIO | FOLHA | DIFERENCA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMB CSC | 4358 | 1024.5 | 1024.5 | 0 |

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; and the `INSERT` statement for your sample data so that we can replicate the problem.

Comment: The query looks like it was written in the 1980s. Since 1992 we have had explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.) in standard SQL. Please don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that for functionary 4358 and 8/2022 there are two rows in the alimentacao table and 52 rows in the movimentos table. You join all these rows and get 2 x 52 = 104 rows for the functionary in your intermediate result. Then you do sums, but all the values are already multifold in the data you are looking at, so you get sums that are too high (multiplied by the number of matching rows in the other table).

Instead aggregate the tables in order to join the sums:

```
SELECT
  fn.uniorg_cgc,
  fn.id,
  COALESCE(fa.sum_valor, 0) AS beneficio,
  COALESCE(fm.sum_valor, 0) AS folha,
  COALESCE(fa.sum_valor, 0) - COALESCE(fm.sum_valor, 0) AS diferencia
FROM funcionarios fn
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT id_funcionario, SUM(valor) AS sum_valor
  FROM funcionario_alimentacao
  WHERE mes_comp = 8
    AND ano_comp = 2022
    AND id_processo IN (53, 153, 75, 175)
  GROUP BY id_funcionario
) fa ON fa.id_funcionario = fn.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT id_funcionario, SUM(valor) AS sum_valor
  FROM funcionario_movimentos
  WHERE mes_competencia = 8
    AND ano_competencia = 2022
    AND cod_verba IN ('E002', 'E017')
  GROUP BY id_funcionario
) fm ON fm.id_funcionario = fa.id_funcionario
ORDER BY fn.uniorg_cgc, fn.id;
```

Comment: BTW: If you want this for the current month instead of hard-coded 8/2022, then use `EXTRACT(month FROM sysdate)` instead of the 8 and `EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate)` instead of 2022.

Comment: thanks for the help and sorry for my 1980s script, im just learning on my own.
Where in the query i have to put the id (4358) from fn table?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `WHERE` clause belongs in the main query after the joins and before the `ORDER BY` clause. I thought it was just an example to get the sample result row. If you want a single ID, then you don't need the `ORDER BY` clause of course. (And you could even correlate the subqueries with `OUTER APPLY` and remove the `GROUP BY` clauses. But Oracle will probably come up with the same execution plan anyway, so don't worry.)